# How to filter relevant value from first parameter in tableau parameter?

Tags: tableau-api, business-intelligence, data-analysis

See the an example here.
I have 3 parameters ,my question is If I select "CH&NO" from  **Tower** drop down option then When I select **Team** parameter should list down only relevant values for "**CH&NO**". How can I solve this issue?

There is option called "Only relevant values" in the Quick filter. But I could not find for Parameter.

[image: I have attached parameter list as image]

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way should be to use Tower, Team, Month as Quick  Filters and set the "Only relevant Values" for all three.

The manual workaround would be to declare 'Team' as a calculated field first, which calculates based on 'Tower' values.

An example:
Team Parameter:

> IF [Tower] == [CH&NO] THEN [*values  related to CH&NO*]
>
> ELSEIF [Tower] == [CH&NO2] THEN [*values  related to CH&NO2*]
>
> END

And then set Team as a parameter. You would also do the same for Month Parameter